# Java Jshell keyboard macros

Tags: java, macros, keyboard, jshell

I have been reading the Oracle [Jshell User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jshell/editing.html#GUID-C6B72B18-E736-43B0-92CA-1B897BCA4079), one feature of Jshell Hotkeys escapes my grasp, the so called keyboard macro function, by definition it sounds quite useful, you should be able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> then type a Word hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> and if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> it writes this word out again to jshell...

The problem is it doesn't work... or I am doing it wrong?! Has someone used this feature? Could you tell me how to use this? how exactly do I have to press the keys? is it hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then hit <kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, let go and then type type <kbd>e</kbd> ?

the Cheatsheets on Github I found just tell you the hotkeys and nothing more...